# YAGO Ontology unparseable by OWL API

Tags: java, parsing, owl, owl-api, turtle-rdf

I'm using OWL API(5.1.7) to try and load the YAGO Ontology. I've downloaded both YAGO taxonomy ([YAGOTaxonomy.ttl](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/yago-naga/yago3.1/yagoTaxonomy.ttl.7z),[YAGOTaxonomy.tsv](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/yago-naga/yago3.1/yagoTaxonomy.tsv.7z)) after doing that I created a simple java file with the following code

```
OWLOntologyManager man = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    try {
        OWLOntology ow = man.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File(filed));
        System.out.println(ow);
    } catch (OWLOntologyCreationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the problem is that when i run it, i get the error that the system can't seem to parse it.

```
 SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.UnparsableOntologyException: Problem parsing file:/H:/toplevel/myDownloads/yagoTaxonomy.tsv.7z
Could not parse ontology.  Either a suitable parser could not be found, or parsing failed.  See parser logs below for explanation.
The following parsers were tried:
1) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFXMLParser@443118b0
2) org.semanticweb.owlapi.owlxml.parser.OWLXMLParser@6bf0219d
3) org.semanticweb.owlapi.functional.parser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxOWLParser@41c2284a
4) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioTurtleDocumentFormatFactory@95fd655c
5) org.semanticweb.owlapi.manchestersyntax.parser.ManchesterOWLSyntaxOntologyParser@c88a337
6) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.NQuadsDocumentFormatFactory@6f9c39ad
7) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.TrigDocumentFormatFactory@27e81c
8) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.NTriplesDocumentFormatFactory@937ecd36
9) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFJsonDocumentFormatFactory@cd748dc3
10) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFJsonLDDocumentFormatFactory@dcacc47d
11) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.N3DocumentFormatFactory@9a5
12) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioRDFXMLDocumentFormatFactory@69b9a3bc
13) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.TrixDocumentFormatFactory@27e82d
14) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.turtle.parser.TurtleOntologyParser@723e88f9
15) org.semanticweb.owlapi.oboformat.OBOFormatOWLAPIParser@4c012563
16) org.semanticweb.owlapi.dlsyntax.parser.DLSyntaxOWLParser@13b3d178
17) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.BinaryRDFDocumentFormatFactory@3bf24493
18) org.semanticweb.owlapi.krss2.parser.KRSS2OWLParser@704deff2
19) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFaDocumentFormatFactory@264e8d
```

I found another stackoverflow question that dealt with something similar [but it doesn't seem to solve my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928222/loading-yago-ontology-with-owl-api)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the stacktrace, it state that could not find sutable parser for '.7z' file you attmpt to load `Problem parsing file:/H:/toplevel/myDownloads/yagoTaxonomy.tsv.7z`

Try out with the unpacked TTL versiion `yagoTaxonomy.ttl.7z`which you post a link to in your question.

Comment: I've tried with both extension, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user2333103 the `ttl` file can be parsed for sure. The `tsv` file is not a proper RDF format. In addition, the OWL API will not be able to parse the triples in the `tsv` file as long as the predicates aren't explicitly declared as object or data property.

Comment: @AKSW I've tried to parse the ttl.7z file, i get the same error. is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @user2333103 there is no parser for 7z files, try to unpack it using 7Zip program  and then try with the unpacked TTL file

Comment: right, 7z isn't supported by OWL API - I'm wondering why you first said you tried already what was suggested in the answer, namely to extract the files in advance?